# Datagridview to draw wafer map

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Currently I'm using C# datagridview to draw a wafer map which contains >500 rows and >700 columns.

However, there are a few issues:

1. Slow performance. As i need to adjust the column width, I have to loop through and assign individually.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvCompleteMapGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
     this.dgvCompleteMapGrid.Columns[i].Width = 8;
   }
   ```
2. I only need to draw the cell border for cells with value as a wafer map has an almost round shape.  I'm using cellpainting event:

   ```
    if (e.Value != null) {
           if (e.Value.ToString() == "")
           {
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;                    
           }
           else
           {                    
               if (e.Value.ToString() == "1")
               {
                   e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime;
               }
               else
               {
                   e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
               }

               //check if the top border set None for neighbor empty value cell
               if (e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top.ToString() == "None")
               {

          e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
               }   
               //repeat the same for left right and bottom
           }
       }
   ```

However, it seems like it will draw multiple border duplicate for most of the cells.

Is Datagridview recommended? I tried to draw rectangle on a panel and the performance is even worse.

Comment: I think you should draw everything on a `DoubleBuffered Panel` and calculate all the points in view for drawing. `700 columns` for a `DataGridView` is a little much even when you don't do anything (custom paint), a little flicker may occur.

Comment: Is your drawing going to get animated or is this just a one-time data visualization? If it's just one-time, draw everything on a bitmap and then display that in a panel as the background. If it's animated, you'll have to do what King King mentioned. And yes, DataGridView is not the right choice here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm already using DoubleBuffered Panel. To draw >500 columns in DGV, the smallest column width is 1 pixel. is it possible to draw a cell smaller than 1 pixel? I'd like to fit in >500 columns in 1 screen without scrollbar.

Comment: @Tombala If DGV is not the right choice, can you suggest what I should try instead?

Comment: I recently wrote a Wire World simulator using a PictureBox (PB) for my canvas. I draw onto a Bitmap behind the scenes. When the bmp is ready, I set the PB.Image = bitmap. I get about 5 FPS having to completely regenerate the whole bitmap so the draw takes a small amount of time. I did create a new PB class deriving from PB, overriding the OnPaint, and setting SmoothingMode, InterpollationMode, CompositingMode and CompositingQuality to increase speed before calling base.OnPaint.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Picturebox that allows for pixellated resizing (versus interpolated). E.g. similar to zooming in on a Microsoft Paint picture.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WireWorld
{
    public class ZoomablePicturebox : PictureBox
    {
        public ZoomablePicturebox()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            pe.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
            pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            pe.Graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            pe.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

To generate the bitmap, I use something like this:

```
// Pick width and height for your case
Bitmap MyBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(retVal))
    g.Clear(BackColor); // Pick a background fill color
// Draw your points, whatever your loop needs to be and your point definition is
foreach (MyPointDef point in _Points)
{
    MyBitmap.SetPixel(point.X, point.Y, point.Color);
}
```

Then I put a picture box in a panel on my form. The panel then provides the scrolling. I can set the picture and zoom as follows:

```
canvasPB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; // Ensures picture is resized as we resize picturebox
canvasPB.Image = MyBitmap;
canvasPB.Height = canvasPB.Image.Height * Zoom; // Zoom is 1, 2, 3, etc, for 1X, 2X, ...
canvasPB.Width = canvasPB.Image.Width * Zoom;
```

canvasPB being the name of the Picturebox on my form I'm trying to use as my canvas.